# DataView RowFilter removes entire row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

I have a DataTable with few columns. Last column is boolean type and it says if the row is valid (should/shouldn't be shown in a DataGridView). Next I have a DataView which is set as a DataSoure to DataGridView:

```
 MyDataView = New DataView(MyDataTable, "Valid = True", Nothing, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
 MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyDataView
```

I am refreshing DataTable in one second interval and everytime I have to decide if rows are valid. Now it works. If Valid attribute is set to false, row disappear from the DGW.

My table has 6 rows (and always will have). What I want to achieve is that if valid is false, I don't want to disappear entire row from DGV. I want only to remove values from cells to look it as empty.

My point is that DGF contains all rows event if row in the table i empty (you can see rows in DGW but empty). Each row has different background color (even rows are white, odd rows are grey).

If a new line was added into the table, I don't want to add new row into DGW, I want to fill emtpy row. If some row was removed from the table, I don't want to remove it from the DGW, I want only clean cells in this row...

Is there a way how to achive this with DataView or I have to check it manually with my code (and disable RowFilter in DataView)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The filter will not work for this.  You will need to handle it in the grid itself.  Here is one way that might help you

```
Private Sub grid_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles grid.CellPainting

    If e.RowIndex > -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex > -1 Then
        Dim oVw As DataRowView
        oVw = TryCast(grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
        If Not oVw Is Nothing AndAlso CBool(oVw.Item("Valid")) Then
            e.Handled = True
            e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, True)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```